# Convert a month name to Integer in VBA, e.g., Jan to 1, Aug to 8

Tags: vba

is there a quick way of converting a month name to an integer? So the integer will always be between 1-12, with January =1 and December =12.

The scenario this is used is:

I made a vba which calculates the sales  between Jan 2016 and whatever the month this year the client wants to calculate. (so it is not necessary the current month)

My idea is to have an input box once the client runs the VBA, and put the desired month in string.

I understand i could just ask the client to convert it to number, but i am curious if it can be done without much hassles.

I hope this explains.

Thanks,

Comment: Use a dictionary?  Otherwise, Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need (i.e., what are you actually trying to do, and *why*; it's possible the solution is not what you think it should be). As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `Application.Match(monthhere, Array("January", "February", "March",...,"December"), 0)`

Comment: @RyanWildry An enum is only useful if you're supplying the month names, not receiving strings of unknown values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't locale aware, but should give you the gist:

```
Public Function MonthNumber(test As String) As Integer
    MonthNumber = DatePart("M", test & "/13/2016")
End Function
```